# Iterating through the pandas df rows and do an operation

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop, dataframe, group-by

I have a pandas dataframe which looks as below

```
    Date          SKU     Balance
0   1/1/2017        X1       8
1   1/1/2017        X2      45
2   1/1/2017        X1      47
3   1/1/2017        X2      16
4   2/1/2017        X1      14
5   2/1/2017        X2      67
6   2/1/2017        X2       9
8   2/1/2017        X1      66
9   2/1/2017        X1     158
```

My first goal is to generate multiple dataframe filtered by every single day

for which I coded

```
df_1stjan = df.query("Date == \"1/1/2017\"")
```

And I got the below result

```
    Date          SKU     Balance
0   1/1/2017        X1       8
1   1/1/2017        X2      45
2   1/1/2017        X1      47
3   1/1/2017        X2      16
```

My second goal is to groupby SKU's and I coded

```
df_1stjan_uSKU = df_1stjan.groupby(['SKU','Date'], \
                         as_index=False).agg({'Balance':'sum'})
```

And I got the below result

```
Date          SKU     Balance
0   1/1/2017        X1      55
1   1/1/2017        X2      61
```

At the moment I could only code to generate df for only one date at a time a

But I need to write a function or loop to automate it for all the days of 2017.

Note the Date column has string dtype

Comment: Can you post what `df1` is supposed to look like? That code doesn't run for me.

Comment: sure , I will edit my question

Comment: I think I get what you are trying to do, however I don't think any of the examples in your sample data will be aggregated because you don't have any overlapping entries in the `SKU` column.  A desired output would be very helpful here.

Comment: sorry chrisz , I have only given the few SKUs , there are lot more but I couldn't display all. In reality each day have mutliple SKUs

Comment: inventory_1stOct = inventory.query("ActivityDate == \"2017-10-01\"")

Comment: I use the above code to extract all the records of 1st oct 2017.How can I loop to extract the records of individual days of 2017. The Date column is in string dtype. I hope you understand my question. This will solve the first part of my question

Comment: @chrisz check out the question , I have edited it and I displayed my desired output

Comment: Thank you for your update, I think I understand what you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are making this too complicated on yourself.  You have pretty much solved your own problem, but I would recommend doing your indexing *after* the initial **`groupby`** and **`agg`**.

***Sample dataframe***:

```
    Balance Date    SKU
0   8   1/1/2017    X1
1   45  1/1/2017    X2
2   47  1/1/2017    X1
3   16  1/1/2017    X2
4   22  1/2/2017    X3
5   24  1/2/2017    X3
6   25  1/3/2017    X4
7   3   1/3/2017    X4
```

**`groupby`** with **`agg`**

```
df1 = df.groupby(['Date', 'SKU'], as_index=False).agg({'Balance':'sum'})

    Date    SKU Balance
0   1/1/2017    X1  55
1   1/1/2017    X2  61
2   1/2/2017    X3  46
3   1/3/2017    X4  28
```

**`to_datetime`** to convert `Date` column

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1.Date, format='%m/%d/%Y')
```

**`date_range`** with all days you would like to access

```
dr = pd.date_range('20170101','20170103')
```

**`loc`** with loop to access slice for each day

```
for d in dr:
    print(df1.loc[df1.Date.isin([d])])

        Date SKU  Balance
0 2017-01-01  X1       55
1 2017-01-01  X2       61

        Date SKU  Balance
2 2017-01-02  X3       46

        Date SKU  Balance
3 2017-01-03  X4       28
```

Comment: Oh yes, can we just write few lines of code to automate it for all the days of 2017.If I write this  , I have to write 365 + 1 lines of code

Comment: Thank you chrisz, I really appreciate your help

Comment: @AhamedMoosa updated my answer, you would just need to change your `date_range` to include all days of 2017 (and probably store in a list as opposed to printing)

Comment: Wow, Thats cool. I am shifting from R to python , hence I may ask some naive question, can you advice me how to store those as dataframes rather than printing

Comment: Just append them to a list, or something like that.  If you're talking about how to store them to some sort of file, there are plenty of answers on SO that address that.

Comment: Noted.Thanks chrisz , your answers have been very helpful.You saved my day

Comment: @AhamedMoosa glad to help, if you found this answer useful, check out [What to do if someone answers my question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 0):

If you do first

```
df_group = df.groupby(['Date', 'C1', 'C2', 'C3', 'SKU']).sum()
```

Then you can create your dfs such as:

```
for date in set(df['Date']):
    df_date = df_group.loc[date].reset_index()
    # and do whatever with df_date, you can save them in a list for example
    # to access them later but maybe the df_group.loc[date].reset_index() is enough for what you need
```

Comment: Hi Ben , Thanks for your answer. However I am not able to implement it. I have edited my question , can you please check if you can help. Thanks.

Comment: @AhamedMoosa you found your answer now, so glad for you :)